# Access VBA: Calculating Median on data using GROUP BY on two columns

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, group-by, median

I am trying to find a way to calculate the median of a dataset in access, that is grouped by two columns, `typeA, typeB`.

This is a sample of the table:

| ID (autonumber) | typeA (large number) | typeB (large number) | total (large number) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 45 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 44 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 19 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 34 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 19 |
| 9 | 2 | 2 | 18 |

Using Access 2016

Currently I am using the following code snippet:

```
Function fMedian(SQLOrTable, GroupFieldName, GroupFieldValue, GroupFieldName2, GroupFieldValue2, MedianFieldName)
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SQLOrTable, dbOpenDynaset)

If IsDate(GroupFieldValue) Then
    GroupFieldValue = "#" & GroupFieldValue & "#"
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(GroupFieldValue) Then
    GroupFieldValue = "'" & Replace(GroupFieldValue, "'", "''") & "'"
End If

If IsDate(GroupFieldValue2) Then
    GroupFieldValue2 = "#" & GroupFieldValue2 & "#"
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(GroupFieldValue) Then
    GroupFieldValue2 = "'" & Replace(GroupFieldValue2, "'", "''") & "'"
End If

rs1.Filter = GroupFieldName & "=" & GroupFieldValue
rs1.Sort = MedianFieldName

Set rs = rs1.OpenRecordset()
rs.Move (rs.RecordCount / 2)

If rs.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
    varMedian1 = rs.Fields(MedianFieldName)
    rs.MoveNext
    fMedian = varMedian1 + rs.Fields(MedianFieldName) / 2
Else
    fMedian = rs.Fields(MedianFieldName)
End If

End Function
```

As it stands, this works great for grouping by one column, but I cannot figure out how to allow it to group by on both `typeA` and `typeB`. I have by editing the `rs1.filter` line but to no avail.

Any help with the code, or a better approach would be appreciated.

Thank you!

NOTE: solved using parfaits solution below. added line `medianVBA = fmedian` before the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an extension of @Fionnuala's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/640348/1422451) to calculate median in MS Access by accommodating an open-ended number of grouping variables.

**VBA** *(save below in a standard module of Access project)*

Code builds a dynamic SQL string for DAO recordset call for later median calculation. Special handling required for groupings with 0-2 records and null values for groupings.

```vb
Public Function MedianVBA(ParamArray Arr() As Variant) As Double
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim N As Long
    Dim tblName As String, numCol As String, grpVals As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim varMedian As Double, fMedian As Double
    
    'BUILD DYNAMIC SQL
    tblName = Arr(0)
    numCol = Arr(1)
    grpVals = " WHERE " & numCol & " IS NOT NULL "
        
    For N = 2 To UBound(Arr) Step 2
        If Arr(N + 1) = "" Or IsNull(Arr(N + 1)) Then
            grpVals = grpVals & " AND " & Arr(N) & " IS NULL"
        ElseIf IsDate(Arr(N + 1)) Then
            grpVals = grpVals & " AND " & Arr(N) & " = #" & Arr(N + 1) & "#"
        Else
            grpVals = grpVals & " AND CStr(" & Arr(N) & ") = '" & Arr(N + 1) & "'"
        End If
    Next N

    strSQL = "SELECT " & numCol _
              & " FROM " & tblName _
              & grpVals _
              & " ORDER BY " & numCol
  
    'CALCULATE MEDIAN
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MedianAcc = fMedian
        GoTo ExitHandle
    ElseIf rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
        MedianAcc = rs.Fields(numCol)
        GoTo ExitHandle
    End If
    
    rs.Move (rs.RecordCount / 2)
    rs.MovePrevious

    If rs.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
        varMedian = rs.Fields(numCol)
        If rs.RecordCount = 2 Then
            rs.MoveLast
        Else
            rs.MoveNext
        End If
        fMedian = (varMedian + rs.Fields(numCol)) / 2
    Else
        fMedian = rs.Fields(numCol)
    End If

    rs.Close
    MedianAcc = fMedian
  
ExitHandle:
    Set rs = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Function
```

Do note, above VBA function uses a `ParamArray` where first argument expects the source table and second column expects the numeric column and the remaining is open-ended for group column name and value pairs. Signature of call is as follows:

```vb
=MedianAcc("table_name", 
           "numeric_col", 
           "group1_column", "group1_value",
           "group2_column", "group2_value", 
           ...)
```

**SQL** *(stored query that calls above VBA function)*

Below runs a one-group and two-group median calculation.

```sql
SELECT t.typeA, t.typeB
       , MedianVBA('[myTable]', '[total]', '[typeA]', t.typeA) AS MedianGrp1, 
       , MedianVBA('[myTable]', '[total]', '[typeA]', t.typeA, '[typeB]', t.typeB) AS MedianGrp2
FROM myTable t
GROUP BY t.typeA, t.typeB
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for this! I've modified my sample table to match the fields in your above query but upon running I receive an error '3464: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'. I believe this is coming from the multiple group by example. When I run just the first it runs, but the median is 0 for all rows.

Comment: Are you certain the second argument in your `MedianVBA` call is a number field? Don't just look and guess, but check in table design. Are you using dates for any grouping? Carefully see the SQL example where first two parameters must be string and grouping value should not be quoted. Finally, you may have oversimplified your data sample in post. Please edit post with data closer to actual if strings/dates/long text are used including if special chars and spaces are used in column/table names.

Comment: Ah good catch yes I had forgot to set fieldB to a number. I will edit my sample with the current table I am testing on! Thanks again

Comment: So does the issue persist? Assuming `fieldB` is `total` in above post, what issue remains? I created a table with exact types and data as posted and ran the SQL query with no issue.

Comment: The issue with the error message is cleared up, however I am getting 0's for the values. I tried an aggregate average alongside them and it calculated that fine if thats any help. The VBA function + sample query are copy and pasted in without any adjustments

Comment: While I still cannot reproduce your issue from posted data and my posted code, I made a small change to handle grouping columns than can be number. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me taking a totally different approach here...

Say you have a Table called `Table1` with fields `Field1`.
To find the median of `Field1` the SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    ((SELECT MAX(B.Field1) AS Field1 FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT A.Field1 FROM Table1 A)
     B) +
    (SELECT MIN(D.Field1) AS Field1 FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT C.Field1 FROM Table1 C ORDER BY C.Field1 DESC) 
    D))
/2 AS MEDIAN FROM Table1
```

(the above split out to make it more readable, I wrote it as only 2 lines)

From there all you have to do is write the vba to make it dynamic - replace 'Table1' with your variable `SQLorTable` and `Field1` with the field to find the median of.

Comment: Seconds after posting I've realised I might have totally misunderstood the question! Did you actually want a median from a dataset where the only info you have about it is a grouped table? That would be calculated fairly differently although the above method could be adapted to do that I think.

Comment: Hello! So what im trying to do is i have a big data set with a couple of identifying fields, and a quantity field. Currenty Im calculating the mean quantity, grouping on two of the identifiers (say fieldA and fieldB). what I am trying to do is make a aggregate function replacing this mean with a median, that I can call in the actual query. Cheers!

Comment: @amisos so you have access to the whole dataset not just the grouped output? In which case the above query could be applied to that, you'd just need to add your ordering parameters (so where I've put `FROM Table1 A` you'd want `FROM Table1 A ORDER BY A.FieldA, A.FieldB`, and same but descending on the second subquery `FROM Table1 C ORDER BY C.FieldA DESC, C.FieldB DESC`)